# Display latest value of a metric in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I am very new to Grafana and I am trying to create a panel which gives the **latest** version of a software of each component. My data source is Prometheus. The query inspector in Grafana is attached below. The issue is the `value` is always 1 while the `version` property is in the `metric` field (i.e. 1.4.3). Ideally it will be table that shows the `job`, `pod` and `service` and `version`

```
{
  "xhrStatus": "complete",
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "api/datasources/proxy/4/api/v1/query_range?query=fabric_version&start=1570982400&end=1571025600&step=43200&timeout=60s"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
      "resultType": "matrix",
      "result": [
        {
          "metric": {
            "endpoint": "https",
            "instance": "10.129.0.13:8443",
            "job": "ibp-os-metrics",
            "namespace": "ibp",
            "pod": "oskrgfu1-7bf78b7ff8-99ktp",
            "service": "ibp-os-metrics",
            "version": "1.4.3"
          },
          "values": [
            [
              1570982400,
              "1"
            ],
            [
              1571025600,
              "1"
            ]
          ]
        },
        {
          "metric": {
            "endpoint": "https",
            "instance": "10.129.0.14:8443",
            "job": "ibp-os-metrics",
            "namespace": "ibp",
            "pod": "oskrgfu3-758874c4dd-xg672",
            "service": "ibp-os-metrics",
            "version": "1.4.3"
          },
          "values": [
            [
              1570982400,
              "1"
            ],
            [
              1571025600,
              "1"
            ]
          ]
        },
        {
          "metric": {
            "endpoint": "https",
            "instance": "10.129.0.15:9443",
            "job": "ibp-org1-metrics",
            "namespace": "ibp",
            "pod": "org1peer1-5794969465-zbfrq",
            "service": "ibp-org1-metrics",
            "version": "1.4.3"
          },
          "values": [
            [
              1570982400,
              "1"
            ],
            [
              1571025600,
              "1"
            ]
          ]
        },
        {
          "metric": {
            "endpoint": "https",
            "instance": "10.130.0.17:8443",
            "job": "ibp-os-metrics",
            "namespace": "ibp",
            "pod": "oskrgfu4-7d7fb7f8d9-hhm4r",
            "service": "ibp-os-metrics",
            "version": "1.4.3"
          },
          "values": [
            [
              1570982400,
              "1"
            ],
            [
              1571025600,
              "1"
            ]
          ]
        },
        {
          "metric": {
            "endpoint": "https",
            "instance": "10.130.0.19:9443",
            "job": "ibp-org1-metrics",
            "namespace": "ibp",
            "pod": "org1peer2-66d6dc8b97-wvxbm",
            "service": "ibp-org1-metrics",
            "version": "1.4.3"
          },
          "values": [
            [
              1570982400,
              "1"
            ],
            [
              1571025600,
              "1"
            ]
          ]
        },
        {
          "metric": {
            "endpoint": "https",
            "instance": "10.131.0.13:8443",
            "job": "ibp-os-metrics",
            "namespace": "ibp",
            "pod": "oskrgfu2-5fc85bfb46-2sfv9",
            "service": "ibp-os-metrics",
            "version": "1.4.3"
          },
          "values": [
            [
              1570982400,
              "1"
            ],
            [
              1571025600,
              "1"
            ]
          ]
        },
        {
          "metric": {
            "endpoint": "https",
            "instance": "10.131.0.15:8443",
            "job": "ibp-os-metrics",
            "namespace": "ibp",
            "pod": "oskrgfu5-b68d5bd7b-564g7",
            "service": "ibp-os-metrics",
            "version": "1.4.3"
          },
          "values": [
            [
              1570982400,
              "1"
            ],
            [
              1571025600,
              "1"
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I can use `fabric-version` query but I cannot customize the table columns

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`"version": "1.4.3"` is a label of your metrics, the value of the metrics in `1`. values of metrics are stored in `"values":[]` array. This metric can be shown as:

```
fabric_version{...,version="1.4.3"}   1
```

How you can fix it:

- Query mentioning version:

  - query: `fabric_version{version="1.4.3"}`
  - you will get the list of pods with version `1.4.3`
  - do same for other versions too
- Change metric definition from code

  - declare `fabric_version` as [gauge](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge)
  - set version value `1.4.3` or whatever before exporting
  - you will get value equal to version instead of 1

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the code. I can query using `fabric_version{version="1.4.3"}` and visualize as table but I cannot customize the columns of the table (always shown as auto)

Comment: @user1055010  have you seen [this](https://grafana.com/docs/features/panels/table_panel/)?

Comment: yes i have tried all types of table transform but the the column names remain the same

Comment: @user1055010 all those columns are actually the labels of the metric. If you want to drop or add or rename some of the labels, you can do it from prometheus config file. [Prometheus configuration doc](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/)

Comment: so you're saying there's no way to hide/show the table columns from Grafana?

Comment: @user1055010 there are some mode under `Table Transform` section where you can modify columns, but in other mode columns are determined by the query.

Comment: yeah i see that i can hide some columns in the `Table Transform` section